# WLST/Python: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (no code object) at line 0

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, jvm-arguments, wlst

I am trying to write some straightforward wlst to update JVM arguments and I keep running into this response:

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
(no code object) at line 0
File "/home/aurban/test.py", line 22
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am completely new to weblogic, wlst and python - I really have no idea what I'm doing. 
I've seen other questions with this error that just ended up being a space somewhere - I've gone through again and again and can't find any spaces where they shouldn't be.

Here's the script

```
import os
import getopt
from java.util import *
from javax.management import *
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter
class SetJVMArgs(object):
 def SetJVMArgs(self,properties):
    try:
     adminUserName=getKeyValue('ADMINUSERNAME',properties)
     adminPassword=getKeyValue('ADMINPASSWORD',properties)
     connect('adminUserName','adminPassword','t3://localhost:7007')
     edit()
     startEdit(-1,-1,'false')
     jvmArgs='-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1248m'
     save()
     activate()
     exit()
```

Comment: A `try` without an accompanying `except` is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Take the WSLT (whatever that is) out of the equation by just running the script directly on the command line. You'll get the same error because as already mentioned, you can't open a `try` block without closing it with either an `except:` or a `finally:`.